# How to join two already sorted arrays into one sorted array in M$ Flow efficiently

Tags: sorting, power-automate

Microsoft Flow doesn't support any sort function for arrays or lists.

For my problems I can use sort function within ODATA request to have some data presorted by the databases I'm accessing. In my case, I want to have a list of all start and end dates from a sharepoint calendar in a single array.

I can pull all dates sorted by the start date and I can pull all dates sorted by the end date into separate arrays. Now I have two sorted arrays which I want to join into a single array.

There are very few possibilites in iterating over an array. But the task has some properties which could ease the problem.

- Two arrays,
- both presorted by the same property as the desired final arrays.
- same size.

Perhaps I'm missing some feature of the ODATA-request or there's a simple workaround. I'd prefer not to use REST-api or messing around with the JSON or manually, but if there's really an elegant solution I won't reject it.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution, but I don't think it is a good one.

Prerequesites are the two already sorted arrays and two additional arrays.
Let's call the two sorted arrays I have extracted from the sharepoint list array A and B.

And let's call the additional arrays array S1 and S2.

1. Then I set up a foreach-loop on array B.
2. Within that loop I filter array A for all elements lesser or equal to the current item of array B.
3. The output of the filter operation is saved to array S1.
4. current item of array B is appendet to array S1.
5. Again filter Array A for all elements, but this time for greater than the current item of array B.
6. save the output of the filter operation to array S2.
7. make a union from S1 and S2.
8. save the output of the union expression to array A.

As every element of array A has to be copied n times for a n-element array, the effort for processing two arrays of n elements is not quite optimal, especially if you consider both arrays already sorted in advance.

- n² comparisons
- 2n²+n copy operations (not taking into account the imperfections of the implementation of flow)

If I'd implement a complete sort from scratch it would perform better, I think, but I also think, there must be other means to join two presorted arrays of compatible content.